# Database/Model design - Person related to another Person

Tags: database-design, relational-database, software-design

I have a Person table which can have a record linked to another record in the same Person table. What is the best approach to represent this?

On the other hand, I need to implement a UI to define the relationship between the two persons. eg:

person 1 is a **wife** of person 2.

Wife is one of the relationships which will be shown in a drop down.

furthermore, in the same UI, they need to have a **note field** for the user to add any notes related to that relationship. I am not sure where the note field should live, do I need a separate table for the relationship?

Comment: You question has a pretty straitghfoward answer: add a relationship type and the person as foreign key related to the table primary key. You can create a RelationshipType table linking it to the drop down box if you want an extensible solution. What is your concern?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually did that already but not sure what to do with the **note** field. Where should that be stored?

Comment: I ended up with Person -> Relationship -> RelationshipType. the Relationship has person1, person2, relationship_type and note fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with Person -> Relationship -> RelationshipType. the Relationship has person1, person2, relationship_type and note fields